# How to count number of rows that meet certain criteria from the entire table?

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm trying to create a table that will tell me for each date and name, how many items were "actively" assigned to each name on that day, from a table that tells me the `datecreated`, the `datedeleted` and the name of the person it was assigned to. The way to count this for a given day is to look at all items created before that day and count the ones not deleted before that day.

Eg someone is assigned an item on the 21st August and then this is deleted on the 24th August. So for the 21st, 22nd and 23rd I would expect this case to be "actively assigned"

I've created a small query that will work for finding it for just one day, but ideally I want to be able to see it for all dates in the database. I cannot figure out how to substitute '20190825' for each `DateCreated` that exists in the table.

```
SELECT Name, MAX(CAST(DateCreated as date)) DateCreated, COUNT(itemid) Number_Assigned 
  FROM dbo.Items
 WHERE CAST(DateCreated as date) <= '20190825' 
   AND (DateDeleted > '20190825' OR DateDeleted IS NULL)
 GROUP BY Name
```

I should have three columns `Name`, `DateCreated` and `Number_Assigned`, where number allocated tells me the number "active" items for that day.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand your query to more days by using a derived table to list the dates.  Then use a `CROSS JOIN` to generate the rows and a `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the data from `items`:

```
SELECT n.Name, v.dte, COUNT(i.itemid) as Number_Assigned
FROM (VALUES (CONVERT(date, '20190822')),
             (CONVERT(date, '20190823')),
             (CONVERT(date, '20190824')),
             (CONVERT(date, '20190825'))
     ) d(dte) CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM items
     ) n LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Items
     ON i.DateCreated <= d.dte AND
        (i.DateDeleted > d.dte OR i.DateDeleted IS NULL)
GROUP BY n.Name, d.dte
ORDER BY n.Name, d.dte;
```